# Upper Triangular Matrix in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have a query which generates the following result set

```
rs = [51,88,93,89,91,26,51,47,47,31,67,68,46,92,39]
```

my matrix size is 5X5 and I want the final result as upper triangular matrix

```
51  88  93  89  91

0   26  51  47  47

0   0   31  67  68

0   0   0   46  92

0   0   0   0   39
```

My code : But does not generate the desired O/P

```
int rowCount = 5;
String[][] result = new String[rowCount][];
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    Cell[] row = sheet.getRow(i);

    result[i] = new String[row.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        if(i<=j){
            result[i][j] = row[j].getContents();
            System.out.print(result[i][j] + " ");
        }else{
            result[i][j] = "0";
            System.out.print(result[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Can you please help what to change in the code to get the proper matrix.

Comment: what is your current output? Can´t you just initiliaze the array to contain only `0` and start your loop at `j = i`?

Comment: is `rs` a `ResultSet` or simply an array? What is the output that you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0's are in the cells where column number is lesser then row number.

```
int rowCount = 5;
int colCount = rowCount;
int[][] result = new int[rowCount][colCount];
int[] input = { 51, 88, 93, 89, 91, 26, 51, 47, 47, 31, 67, 68, 46, 92, 39};
int k = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
  for (int column = 0; column < colCount; column++) {
    result[row][column] = row > column ? 0 : input[k++];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alexey Gromov "0's are in the cells where column number is lesser then row number." that's exactly I thought but was not able to implement. .. thanks again it was a big help